# how to finish complete 4 steps of tcp teardown in network programming

Tags: c, linux, tcp, network-programming

in network programming, I wrote 2 TCP programs A and B 
when a tcp connection is established betweeen A and B
if I want to close it, I can use the following code snippets on A:

```
int main(){
......    //blabla
shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RDWR);
close(sockfd);
return;   // program finish
}
```

in this way, the socket will send FIN/ACK to B and receive an ACK from B.
I use tcpdump to capture packets, and I notice there are only FIN/ACK from A to B
and ACK from B to A, so there are only 2 steps. But for tcp teardown, there should be 4 steps, FIN/ACK from B to A and ACK from A to B sebsequently. So, it is incomplete.

so my questions how to finish the 4 steps, consequently, I want to know

1  how can program B detect A has sent SYN/ACK, if B is doing `n=recv();` then if n is `0`, it means A has done an active close. but if B is idle , how to detect? if B is doing doing `n=sendto()`, I think if `n<0`, then A does an active close, but my test seems my thinking is wrong.

2  how can I make the program A finish the TCP teardown 4 steps before `return` (exit the program)

thanks!

Comment: You don't need to call shutdown() if the next operation is close(): the close() will send the FIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A has done an active close. but if B is idle , how to detect

As far as I know your process doesn't get informed unless you do a `send` / `recv` (or equivalent).

- A `send` should trigger a `SIGPIPE` signal or return `-1` with `errno = EPIPE`
- A `recv` should return 0 to signal EOF

Ideally your program (B) should already be **monitoring the file descriptor for available input** (perhaps with `select(2)`, `poll(2)` or equivalent). If you do this, once the peer closes its end of the connection the file descriptor you are monitoring will become "interesting" for read and a subsequent `read` will return 0.

Personally I would suggest `epoll(2)`, but keep in mind it's Linux-specific.

> how can I make the program A finish the TCP teardown 4 steps before
>   return (exit the program)

When your process dies, one of the things done by the OS is to **close all its file descriptors**. Part of this process is also closing sockets and closing sockets means closing the connection (the last 2 segments you mentioned).

Comment: but when A program finishes, I see B is still keeping in `CLOSE_WAIT` state unless I quit B using `CTRL+C`

Comment: @user1944267 that's right. It is waiting for you to close that descriptor.

Comment: thanks, I'm just afraid, if A exit after it sends FIN/ACK and receives ACK, then the FIN/ACK from B can't be acknowledged by A.

Comment: BTW, I have a new related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067015/blocking-pcap-and-multiple-i-o-select

Comment: @user1944267 But when `A` exits the OS will still keep some information about that connection, specifically to be able to answer B. You can check it out with `netstat -tlnp`