# blocking pcap and multiple I/O `select `

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, libpcap

I want to use pcap to capture packets
and then send the captured packets to another host
my source code snippets are like:

```
            for(;;){
                    pcap_packet = pcap_next(pcap_handler, &pcap_header);
                    if(pcap_packet !=NULL)
                    printf("capture a packet with length of %d\n", pcap_header.len);

                    // send the packet as payload to the sender, excluding the Ethernet Header
                    n = send(sd_proxy, pcap_packet+ETHERNET_HDR_LEN, pcap_header.len-ETHERNET_HDR_LEN, 0);
                    if(n<0){
                            shutdown(connfd, SHUT_RDWR);
                            close(connfd);
                            break;
                    } new  

            }
```

so basically, I want program to be blocked by the pcap_next, once a
the socket sd_proxy establishes a TCP connection with the other host,
if the other host initiate an active TCP close, I want to detect this 
active close. Ideally, I should use a `select` and a `n=recv(rd_fd, ...)`
if the other host initiates a active close, `select` will notice there is something with `rd_fd` and then I see whether 'n=0' or not.
but with pcap, select can't cooperate with pcap

so how to finish my task?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> select can't cooperate with pcap

Why not?  Have you tried using `pcap_get_selectable_fd()` on `pcap_handler` and adding the resulting file descriptor to the file descriptor set in your `select()` call?

You're working on Linux, so that should Just Work.

(If you were running on a system that uses BPF, such as *BSD or OS X, you might have problems with this, at least with older versions of those OSes; various *BSDs have had their select-with-BPF bugs fixed for a while; on OS X, I fixed it in Lion, so it could have problems on Snow Leopard and earlier.)

Comment: See [this mail message](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.network.tcpdump.devel/6288/focus=6293) for more information.